# Why is this shared library not getting linked?

Tags: compiler-construction, cuda, compilation, linker, shared-libraries

I am trying to generate traces of GPGPU benchmarks on X86 cpu using GPUocelot. For this reason, I am compiling the benchmarks with -locelot and -locelotTrace linker flags. My benchmarks compile and execute fine. However, traces are not getting generated.

compile command:

```
nvcc -arch=sm_20 bfs.cu -o bfs -locelot -locelotTrace
```

`libocelot.so` and `libocelotTrace.so` are located in `/usr/local/lib` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`.

I verified the shared libraries that are linked to this binary using `ldd`. I can see that `libocelot.so` is linked but I don't see `libocelottrace.so`.

I think this is the issue that's resulting in traces not getting generated. How can I make sure the binary is linked to `libocelottrace.so`?

Comment: From what [I can see](http://code.google.com/p/gpuocelot/wiki/TraceGeneration) enabling trace in gpuocelot is more involved than just linking in another library.  If the library is not getting linked in, perhaps it's because you haven't taken the necessary steps to enable trace in your code base, and thus there is no dependency on the trace library (note the mention of `--as-needed` below).

Answer (score 1):

> I can see that `libocelot.so` is linked but I don't see `libocelottrace.so`

This is likely because

- Your compiler uses `--as-needed` linker flag (you should see that if you invoke `nvcc` with `-v` flag), and
- Your command line is incorrect. Try `nvcc -arch=sm_20 bfs.cu -o bfs -locelotTrace -locelot` instead (the order of libraries on command line *matters*).